# How to pass a variable to event listener in Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I wrote a Greasemonkey script for Firefox which adds return type and parameters names for each method on a current .NET documentation web page. For example, on a web page describing [`SortedSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx) class `Add(T)` will be changed to `bool Add(T item)` signature and so on. The script properly downloads signatures of all methods - see `console.log(s)`. I can also change content of the Name column in each row by uncommenting `node.textContent = "*changed*"`. Unfortunately, if I want to set the content of the Name column to the appropriate signatures, this works only for the first row. It looks like the node variable is not properly passed to the event listerer in the for loop.

Below is the complete script code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Unnamed Script 785375
// @include  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/*
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

//get all links in Name column of Constructors, Properties and Methods tables
var nodes = document.evaluate("//table[@id='idConstructors' or @id='idProperties' or @id='idMethods']/tbody/tr/td[@data-th='Name']/a",
                              document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

//update text of each link to contain the full signature of the class member
for (var i = nodes.snapshotLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var node = nodes.snapshotItem(i);
  //node.textContent = "*changed*";

  //the signature is found in the first pre tag on the webpage pointed by the current link
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var html = document.createElement('html');
    html.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    var elements = html.getElementsByTagName('pre');
    var s = elements[0].textContent;
    s = s.replace(/\n/g, "");   //remove unnecessary white space from the signature
    s = s.replace(/\t/g, " ");
    s = s.replace(/\( /g, "(");
    console.log(s);
    node.textContent = s;
  });
  oReq.open("GET", node.getAttribute("href"));
  oReq.send();
}
```

and the current incorrect result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It is a common problem with JavaScript closure in loop.
Changing:

```
var node = nodes.snapshotItem(i);
```

to:

```
const node = nodes.snapshotItem(i);
```

will help.